# Check if a file pattern exists remotely using python fabric

Tags: python, fabric

Using python fabric, how do I check if a file pattern such as `/foo/bar_*` exists remotely on a machine?
It would be useful to also get a list of those files which matched.

Answer (score 0):

I use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) from the python standard library.

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob("/for/bar_*"):
    print(filename)
```

---

I just reread your question - you want to know this on the remote computer.

Although I can't find an API that does this for you, I have noticed a couple of ways.

1. [get](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.get)

This solution only really works if you want to have the files locally, or their size is negligable.

2. [echo (via run)](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run)

This could look something like this;

```
@task
def task_name():
    glob = "/foo/bar_*"
    result = run("echo " + glob)
    if result == glob:
        print("This pattern does not match a file/folder on the target machine")
    else:
        print("This pattern matched!")
```

That solves the issue of needing to know if the file exists. However it does have problems as far as working out which files exist - as parsing it out isn't that trivial (ie, files/folders with spaces in their names). It should get you started for now though.